# Create object of wsc file in htm and access the wsc functions

Tags: html, vbscript

I am trying to access a function of wsc file by using the below code in htm file. I am getting exception when the CreateObject is called in the htm file.

```
Set obj= CreateObject("MyFuns.WSC")
obj.WriteData "DEBUG"
Set obj= Nothing
```

When I use the same code to invoke the wsc from vbs file then I am not seeing any error

Do I need do any setting in the internet explorer to use wsc from the htm file. FYI, I am using windows 10

Comment: Modern browsers do not support VBScript even Microsoft Internet Explorer 11 and above dropped support for it in Standards Mode.

Comment: I am able to use the normal vbscript code in the html but when i try to create the object of wsc file then only i am getting this error (429)

Comment: What is the exact error when you try to call the wsc in the HTML file?

Comment: I have logged the error number and description .Error description says (ActiveX component can't create object)

Comment: Probably security setting in the browser, check the ActiveX Script custom settings on the security tab in Internet Explorer.

Comment: I able to fix the issue. The issue got fixed after I have registered the WSC with 32 bit version of regsvr32  "C:\WINDOWS\SYSWOW64\REGSVR32.EXE"

Answer (score 0):

The issue got fixed after I register the wsc with 32 bit version regsvr32 i.e

C:\WINDOWS\SYSWOW64\REGSVR32.EXE